# Reading only file names from s3 using python

Tags: python, amazon-s3

Trying to get the filenames using aws commands in python.But getting error.

```
import subprocess
output=subprocess.check_output(['aws', 's3', 'ls', 's3://dev-lake/staging/20181111/', '--recursive', '--human-readable', '--summarize', '|','awk', '{print $4}'])
print output
```

Error

```
Unknown options: |,awk,{print $4}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "list.py", line 2, in <module>
    output=subprocess.check_output(['aws', 's3', 'ls', 's3://sdx-dev-lake/staging/20181111/', '--recursive', '--human-readable', '--summarize', '|','awk', '{print $4}'])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 219, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['aws', 's3', 'ls', 's3://sdx-dev-lake/staging/20181111/', '--recursive', '--human-readable', '--summarize', '|', 'awk', '{print $4}']' returned non-zero exit status 255
```

Comment: please add the error message. it will help also.

Comment: It looks like your bash command is the problem. `subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command ... returned non-zero exit status 255` Does it work when you exec it from bash?

Comment: You do not have a shell, so you can't use  pipes in your command eg. `cmd1 | cmd2`. Either use the option `shell=True` and pass the whole command as a single string or create the pipe in python using `Popen`.

Comment: @Dunes That's not necessarily true you can use pipe for example with os module. `os.system("cmd1 | cmd2")`

Comment: @RaoslawSzamszur `os.system` executes the command in a subshell. It's semantically the same thing as using `shell=True`.

Comment: @Dunes good to know, thanks!